# Imagepull back off : Kubernetes mongo deployment

Tags: mongodb, powershell, kubernetes, deployment, virtualbox

I tried creating a deployment with minikube cluster connected to virtual box.But it results with below mentioned Imagepullbackoff error(Passed commands on Windows powershell-admin rights)
I tried with docker as a driver but same result.Help me out!!

PS C:\Windows\system32>kubectl get pod
NAME                                  READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
mongo-express-98c6ff4b4-l7jmn         0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          116m
mongodb-deployment-67dcfb9c9f-mfvxr   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          116m

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> kubectl describe pod
Name:         mongo-express-98c6ff4b4-l7jmn
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.59.113
Start Time:   Thu, 30 Jun 2022 19:10:41 +0530
Labels:       app=mongo-express
              pod-template-hash=98c6ff4b4
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           172.17.0.4
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.4
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mongo-express-98c6ff4b4
Containers:
  mongo-express:
    Container ID:
    Image:          mongo-express
    Image ID:
    Port:           8081/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME:  <set to the key 'mongo-root-username' in secret 'mongodb-secret'>  Optional: false
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD:  <set to the key 'mongo-root-password' in secret 'mongodb-secret'>  Optional: false
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER:         <set to the key 'database_url' of config map 'mongodb-configmap'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-lp9nk (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-lp9nk:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  60m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mongo-express-98c6ff4b4-l7jmn to minikube
  Warning  Failed     58m (x6 over 59m)    kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    58m (x4 over 59m)    kubelet            Pulling image "mongo-express"
  Warning  Failed     58m (x4 over 59m)    kubelet            Failed to pull image "mongo-express": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: no such host
  Warning  Failed     58m (x4 over 59m)    kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     29m (x2 over 36m)    kubelet            Failed to pull image "mongo-express": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded
  Normal   BackOff    19m (x141 over 59m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "mongo-express"


Name:         mongodb-deployment-67dcfb9c9f-mfvxr
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.59.113
Start Time:   Thu, 30 Jun 2022 19:10:32 +0530
Labels:       app=mongodb
              pod-template-hash=67dcfb9c9f
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           172.17.0.3
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.3
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mongodb-deployment-67dcfb9c9f
Containers:
  mongodb:
    Container ID:
    Image:          mongo
    Image ID:
    Port:           27017/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:  <set to the key 'mongo-root-username' in secret 'mongodb-secret'>  Optional: false
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'mongo-root-password' in secret 'mongodb-secret'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-ft77v (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-ft77v:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  60m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mongodb-deployment-67dcfb9c9f-mfvxr to minikube
  Warning  Failed     58m (x6 over 60m)    kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    58m (x4 over 60m)    kubelet            Pulling image "mongo"
  Warning  Failed     58m (x4 over 60m)    kubelet            Failed to pull image "mongo": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: no such host
  Warning  Failed     58m (x4 over 60m)    kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     34m                  kubelet            Failed to pull image "mongo": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded
  Normal   BackOff    19m (x134 over 60m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "mongo"
```

Comment: Your nodes are not able to communicate with the registry, check Virtual box network settings.

Comment: I tried changing the internet settings on virtual box - It works fine with nginx deployment & sample 'Hello minikube deployment'. But with mongodb deployment alone I am getting error again as "Crashloopoff/Imagepullbackoff" - @Sam

Answer (score 4):

Try to pull image first, then create deployment.

```
minikube image pull mongo
```

**UPD**: Sometimes even `image pull` doesn't help. minikube developers said that you can curl to check whether you can connect to repo or not. There also may be ISP issues. Temporary changing my ISP to mobile data and installing needed pods worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The error `context deadline exceeded` means that minikube was unable to pull mongo-express image with the expected time frame.

You can fix this by directly pulling your image using the below command before creating your deployment.

```
minikube image pull mongo-express
```

Answer (score 2):

I got inspiration from elver answer and [this github discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/14806) .

Indeed, it is because the image you want to pull is too large and the default time setting to pull an image is shorter. Thus, you should pull this image to your local first by below example command then recreate your deployment:

> minikube ssh docker pull mongo